# Joint Distribution of sum of Bernoulli stochastic processes

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independent and identically distributed (iid) Bernoulli random variables. For each $k,$
$$P\{X=k\} =  p, \text{       } 0 <p<1.$$
Set $N_0 = 0$ and $t=1,2, \ldots,$ set $$N=\sum_{k=1}^{t} X_k.$$

Find the joint distribution of $$P\{N_{t_1} = i_1, \ldots, N_{t_d} =i_d \}$$

Comment: Repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3733385/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. That one contained errors and it was closed for that reason. The one here is the updated version

Comment: You are supposed to edit the previous post to add context. It will then be reopened.

Comment: I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_d$, one can write $P(N_{t_1}=i_1,\ldots,N_{t_d}=i_d)=P(N_{t_1}=i_1,N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=i_2-i_1,\ldots)$.
Each RV of the form $N_{t_k}-N_{t_{k-1}}$ is $Bin(t_k-t_{k-1},p)$ independent of the others.

To conclude, the probability is $\prod {t_k-t_{k-1} \choose i_k-i_{k-1}}p^{i_k-i_{k-1}}(1-p)^{t_k-t_{k-1}-(i_k-i_{k-1})}=p^{i_d}(1-p)^{t_d-i_d}\prod {t_k-t_{k-1} \choose i_k-i_{k-1}}$

Comment: Is it possible to also find $P\{ N_{t_1}-i_1, \ldots, N_{t_d} \}$?

Comment: I don't understand this notation.

Comment: I still don't follow. The last expression is exactly what is calculated in my answer.